# Mysqldump warning

Tags: php, file, xampp, mysql

So this is breaking my head.. I'm trying to use php to backup (and possibly restore a mysql database.) nothing too complicated but it just wont budge...

```
$mysqlDatabaseName ='ccdb';
$mysqlUserName ='root';
$mysqlPassword ='root';
$mysqlHostName ='localhost';
$time = time();
$mysqlExportPath ='C:\Server-Xampp\htdocs\DBbackup\ccdb-backup-' . $time . '.sql';    

$command='mysqldump -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' > "' .$mysqlExportPath. '"';
    exec($command,$output=array(),$return);
```

$return gives me 1, a file is created but it is EMPTY.

I've tried with forward and backwards slashes for the path, doesn't help. Also added the host into the command, no change...

I've looked around the web but most people just state "it's a warning" which, may be a very good response but it doesnt really tell me anything or how to fix it.

I thought "ok, must be entering something wrong" and tried the exact same code in my shell to see,

```
mysqldump -uroot -proot ccdb > "C:\Server-Xampp\htdocs\DBbackup\ccdb-backup-0000000000.sql"
```

created a file of 23KB... So the principle behind it is okay.. probably some tiny sytax error or something..

Any solutions or hints are welcome

oh yeah, running Xampp v3.2.1 as a localhost

UPDATE:
changed something in my apache settings and all of a sudden the error started showing up, finally a hint.

> 'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

tried to bypass by giving it the path to mysqldump but no luck :(

```
    $mysqlDatabaseName ='ccdb';
$mysqlUserName ='root';
$mysqlPassword ='root';
$mysqlHostName ='localhost';
$time = time();
$mysqlExportPath ='C:\Server-Xampp\htdocs\DBbackup\ccdb-backup-' . $time . '.sql';
$dump  = 'C:\Server-Xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldumb.exe';


$command= $dump . ' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' > "' .$mysqlExportPath. '"';
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
var_dump($worked);
```

Same error...(yes also tried without .exe) Any ideas?

Comment: Is `mysqldump` installed? Sounds like it can't be found in your PATH

Comment: well, I'm not sure if there are any other requirements for it to be "installed" but I have found the mysqldump.exe file at that location. So I am assumin so, yes.

Comment: Hmmm. Yeah i think you need to add mysqldump to your PATH. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.1/en/mysql-installation-windows-path.html. In your PATH you should have `C:\Server-Xampp\mysql\bin`

Comment: Added both 
;C:\Server-Xampp\mysql\bin
;C:\Server-Xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe
Restarted the server, still the same error.

Comment: Have you restarted windows?

Comment: I had not even considered that... I should restart my machine more often... it had been weeks.. THANK YOU guys! :)